# Cannot modify column type to unsigned bigint

Tags: mysql

I want to modify the datatype of a primary key column to be "unsigned bigint" :

```
alter table historique_position modify column histo_id unsigned bigint;
```

When I executed this statement then I got an error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'unsigned bigint' at line 1
>       [Err] alter table historique_position modify column histo_id unsigned bigint;

So what is wrong ?

Comment: It is always useful if you show us the error message that you recieved. In your question !

Comment: ok , I included it in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to say "unsigned" after type.

```
alter table historique_position modify column histo_id bigint unsigned;
```

Comment: I'm reading on some website either `modify some_column` or `modify column some_column`. Which is correct, and is there a difference ?

Comment: It is about the database server you are using. Check it's documentation for correct format.